# Transform figure blocks with internet explorer (i have ie11)

Tags: html, css

Hello i am using this code to flip my block on my website:

```
    .tegels {
    /*position:relative;*/
    width:25.2%;
    height:37.4%;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin-top:3.5vw;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:4.8%;
    margin-right:2%;
    list-style-type: none;

    display:inline-block;
}

.tegels figure {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left:-3vw;
    width:100%;
}
.tegels figure img {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    margin-left:3vw;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.tegels figure figcaption {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    margin-left:3vw;

    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
}
.tegels figure h2 {
    font-family:Garamond, Georgia, serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:2.1vw;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:1vw;


}
.tegels figure p {
    display:block;
    font-family:Garamond, Georgia, serif;
    font-size:1.5vw;
    line-height:1.7vw;
    margin:0;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}
.tegels figure figcaption {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:2vw 1vw;
    background-color:rgba(204,204,204, 0.5);
    text-align:center;
    backface-visibility:hidden;

    -webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
    transform:rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform:all .01s;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s
}
.tegels figure img {
    backface-visibility:hidden;

    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s
}
.tegels figure:hover img,figure.hover img {

    -webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(90deg);
    transform:rotateY(90deg)
}
.tegels figure:hover figcaption,figure.hover figcaption {

    -webkit-transform:rotateY(0);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(0);
    transform:rotateY(0)
}
```

I searched for 3 hours for a solution but i couldn't find it. So that's why i am asking it on the best website forum of all time. Haha, thanks for your time to read this for me. My website is online at [www.gester.nl](http://www.gester.nl). I looked for codes to target the internet explorer but it did'nt work with my version so i don't know where the problem is in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks pretty much a bug in `IE11` with `windows 10` with `backface-visibility` and `WebGL`.

I have tested it in:

- `IE10` with `Windows 8`
- `IE10` with `Windows 7`
- `IE11` with `Windows 8.1`
- `IE11` with `Windows 7`

All they work properly

Please see the **known issues** from [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=backface-visibility).

I haven't found a solution yet but you know what's the error about.

Comment: That is good to know, i thought i did something wrong there. Thanks for your answer have a nice day!